# AVAudioPlayer keeping app in loading screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

When I use this code to play my music in my first scene, the app shows the loading screen but then stays there and doesn't go into my main menu or anything else. Any suggestions?

```
        NSError *error;
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"POL-parallel-fields-short" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    [player setVolume:0.1];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [player prepareToPlay];

    SKAction*   playAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [player play];
        }];
    SKAction *playMusic = [SKAction repeatActionForever:playAction];

    [self runAction:playMusic];
```

Comment: When you switch scene all actions stops automatically. You should play again, my suggestion is use instance method.

Comment: @Valar Morghulis After a comment the poster is made in another question of his, I understood the loading screen he refers to is the app splash screen, and not a custom loading screen he has created, hence, no switching of screen.

Comment: @Nicholas Whitley as I've commented in your other post- I've read someplace about someone complaining about similar issue, and he found out that he accidentally created an infinite loop that caused the app to not execute the code that actually run the rest of the app. Does this also occurs after the modifications you've made according to my answer in your other post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest create MusicHelper instance.

```
//MusicHelper.m

@interface MusicHelper()
@property (nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;
@end

@implementation MusicHelper

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MusicHelper * _sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init]; });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

- (void)playBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)filename {
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:filename withExtension:nil];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
}

- (void)pauseBackgroundMusic
{
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer pause];
}

@end
```

---

```
//MusicHelper.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import AVFoundation;

@interface MusicHelper : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;
- (void)playBackgroundMusic:(NSString *)filename;
- (void)pauseBackgroundMusic;

@end
```

You can call like this in from any scene.

```
[[MusicHelper sharedInstance] playBackgroundMusic:@"yourMusic.mp3"]; //Play
[[MusicHelper sharedInstance] pauseBackgroundMusic]; //Stop
```